# Sorting Array and add element at the beginning of Array

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to sort alphabetically the NSMutableArray and add an object to the beginning of array.

For example :

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red",@"Blue",@"Green",nil];
```

I want in return myarray = "blue","green",Red";

and then I have to add "multicolor" option at the beginning of array.

So myarray becomes: "multicolor","blue","green",Red";

Or if it is possible to sort array without disturbing the "multicolor" option (which will be at the first place), this could also be acceptable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of the `sort*` methods to sort the array.

Use `insertObject:atIndex:` with index `0` to insert at the beginning of the array.

Details can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Did you read the documentation I pointed you to (especially the sort* Methods)? What part of it don't you understand? (There's an example at `sortUsingComparator:` when you click on the `NSComparator` link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparator)

Comment: sortusingcomparator how to use it

Comment: I got my result by using this: myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]]; [myArray insertObject:@"multicolor" atIndex:0];

Comment: Like CodeBrickie said NSArray has sortmethods for the use you want. [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] might be the easiest option if you want it sorted alphabetical.